# they'll burn for it

Tags: meaning

This is from a book, *Jumping Over Shadows: A Memoir*

But, in this context:

> Kindly inform the Church of England they have loused up the most beautiful prose ever written, whoever told them to tinker with the Volgate Latin? **They'll burn for it**, you mark my words.

So just to confirm as I believe the saying in bold, means, "They'll be burned for it". Is this because it's in old English? Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: It's an allusion to burning in Hell.

Comment: ***Hwæt?*** **[Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English) this most certainly is *not!***

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=burn+in+hell%2C+be+burned+in+hell&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cburn%20in%20hell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbe%20burned%20in%20hell%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It's *Vulgate*.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is meant literally "they will burn for it" and refers indirectly to ultimately burning in the fires of hell as a result of the transgression.

My guess is the speaker meant it tongue in cheek (sarcastic 'kindly inform', informal 'loused', mild 'tinker', don't usually add up to eternal damnation for changing a latin phrase), but you're the one with the full text.

I doubt it has anything to do with Old English which is a very different and sometimes [indecipherable](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/diagram_4English.html) older form of English.

Comment: æþeling aérgod      unblíðe sæt· þolode ðrýðswýð

Answer (score 0):

"Burn" in modern English is one of a number of verbs that can be used transitively to describe the doing of an action and intransitively to describe the undergoing of that action. One can burn wood: wood burns. The manager opens the store at 10; the store opens at 10. "This nonstick pan cleans easily." "This book reads like a Greek tragedy."

Answer (score 0):

Burning at the stake was a punishment that this phrase might refer to.

If caught, and found guilty, they would burn for it (the crime).